# How to use function callbacks in Nodejs with xml2js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am using xml2js to parse XML documents in Nodejs.

The XML files are hosted remotely so I use Node.js http request to get the xml data and then parse it with xml2js like this:

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

function getValue(){
    var options = {
      hostname: myHost,
      path: myPath,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': myAuthString
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function (response) {
        parser.parseString(response); 
      });
    });
    req.end();
}
parser.on('end', function(result) {
    // Output the distribution plans to console
     eyes.inspect(result);
     // Get the value that I want to use
     var returnThis = result['myKey'];
});
```

The above code works, I get the XML data when the http request receives the "data" event, then the xml2js parser parses the XML and I get the data on the "end" event of the parsing.

My question is, how do I use callbacks to return the "returnThis" variable value  back to the getValue function?

For example, if I am retrieving a persons name from the XML I would like this to work:

```
console.log("The returned name is: " + getValue());
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated! TIA!

Comment: can always send the parse a call back , to call after it's done, or you can return promise, or throw event. one less attractive option is to set it to some scope that has both functions

Comment: @AbrahamAdam thanks for the suggestion, I am unfamiliar with callbacks, any chance you could post an example of sending the parse a callback? Many thanks!

Comment: deleted my answer since @yzarubin answer shows the callback idea well, I will write another one for the event idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example with event

```
var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    parseEmitter = new emitter();
function getValue(trigger){
    var options = {
      hostname: myHost,
      path: myPath,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': myAuthString
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
      parser.on('end', function(result) {
        // Output the distribution plans to console
        eyes.inspect(result);
        callback(null, result['myKey'])
      });
      res.on('data', function (response) {
        parser.parseString(response); 
      });
    });
    parser.on('end', function(result) {
      // Output the distribution plans to console
      eyes.inspect(result);
      // Get the value that I want to use
      var returnThis = result['myKey'];
      trigger.emit('log', returnThis);
    });
    req.end();
}
parseEmitter.on('log', function(value) {
  console.log('The return name is '+value);
}
getValue(parseEmitter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function getValue(callback){
    var options = {
      hostname: myHost,
      path: myPath,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': myAuthString
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
      parser.on('end', function(result) {
        // Output the distribution plans to console
        eyes.inspect(result);
        callback(null, result['myKey'])
      });
      res.on('data', function (response) {
        parser.parseString(response); 
      });
    });
    req.end();
}
```

To use your function, you will need to do call your function as such:

```
getValue(function(err, res){
  // res should equal myKey
  console.log(res)

})
```